# How to do str.strip() for every line in a text file? Unix

Tags: string, unix, sed, grep, strip

I could do the following in python to clean and strip unwanted whitespaces, but **can it be done just through the terminal by other means like `sed` , `grep` or something?**

```
outfile = open('textstripped.txt','w+','utf8')
for i in open('textfile.txt','r','utf8'):
  print>>outfile, i.strip()
```

Comment: It can, but what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i'm just trying to strip all lines in the textfiles because my annotators always typed extra trailing whitespaces and sometimes heading ones too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat input.txt | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' > output.txt
```

This gets rid of the leading and trailing white spaces..

EDIT: `sed -e "s/^[ \t]+//; s/[ \t]+$//" -i .bk input.txt`

This does in place file editing, and saves backup to input.txt.bk (and saves a process as some suggested)

Comment: pardon my regex noobiness, could you explain the sed? `^[\t]*` means heading whitespaces and `[ \t]*$` means trailing whitespaces right? would `[\s\t]*` do the same as `[ \t]*`?

Comment: `\s` isn't recognized by all versions of Sed

Comment: @2er0 `[\s]*` should be able to replace `[ \t]*`. However, the previous form may have portability issue depending on which sed you use. e.g. on my Mac laptop, I have to use `[ \t]*`

Comment: Yep, I was fighting with this on my Mac as well (otherwise, I'd have beatean zzk ;-)

Comment: You should pass the file straight to sed, to eliminate one unnecessary `cat` process.

Comment: Also, that has two separate expressions, you should just be able to OR them together

Answer (score 2):

Using `perl` on the command line:

`perl -lpe 's/^\s+//; s/\s+$//' file.txt > stripped.txt`

Answer (score 2):

This solution is based on sed man page:

```
sed 'y/\t/ /;s/^ *//;s/ *$//' input > output
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Centering-lines

Description:

> `y\t/ /` replaces tabs with spaces
>
> `s/^ *//` removes leading spaces
>
> `s/ *$//` removes trailing spaces

Answer (score 1):

`sed -E "s/(^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$)//" < input > output`

Or if you have a GNU-compliant version of SED:

`sed -E "s/^\s+|\s+$//g" < in > out`

If you have a Mac, I recommed getting `homebrew` and installing `gnu-sed`.
Then, `alias sed=gsed`.